# Show that $\mathbb{C}^n$ has a basis consisting of generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am learning a proof showing that $\mathbb{C}^n$ has a basis consisting of generalized eigenvectors.

The proof uses that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a direct sum of $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda_1I)^{a_1},...,\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda_k)^{a_k}$. Here $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with char. polynomial factorized as $(-1)^n(\lambda-\lambda_1)^{a_1}\cdots (\lambda-\lambda_k)^{a_k}$, where $\lambda_i$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ and $a_i$ the corresponding algebraic multiplicity.

From this we select a basis $\{\bar{v}_{1,1},\dots,\bar{v}_{1,n_i}\}$ for each $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda_iI)^{a_i}$ and the union of these bases is then the basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$. But when showing that this union is linearly independent, I came across a step that I couldn't follow.

It says that the union $\{\bar{v}_{1,n_1},\dots, \bar{v}_{1,n_i},\dots,\bar{v}_{k,1},\dots,\bar{v}_{k,n_k} \}$ is linearly independent since if $$\sum_{i=1}^k \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n_i}a_{i,j}\bar{v}_{i,j} \right)=0, $$ then *from the definition of a direct sum*, we must have $\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}a_{i,j}\bar{v}_{i,j} = 0$ for each $i$.

And from that, because we know that $\{\bar{v}_{i,1}, \dots, \bar{v}_{i,n_i} \}$ are linearly independent, we must have that each $a_{i,j}$ is equal to zero.

The part I don't understand is the part I wrote in cursive. The fact that we have this direct sum means that each vector $\bar{w} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ can be written uniquely as a sum where each term in the sum is a vector from each eigenspace $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda_iI)^{a_i},$ but why does it follow then that $\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}a_{i,j}\bar{v}_{i,j} = 0$ for each $i$?